# Jquery DataTables - specific pagination load depending on data, page.jumpToData()

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a dataTable v1.10.5 that has A LOT of data... one column is a date and we have it sorting 'Descending' so latest records show first. We have the table paginated so its easy to see the whole thing in chunks.

There could be hundreds of future dated records, a few on todays date, and a load of previous ones. Is it possible to arrive on page load were you see todays dated records first? EG: there are 10 pages and records with todays date start on page 3 so we see page 3 first? from there we can manually select what pages to view as normal.

Im loading the DataTables-1.10.5.js and page.jumpToData().js

but the jumpToData part of the code is not working :(
Am I doing something wrong?

Simplified Snapshot of code:

```
<table id="E_games" class="table table-bordered tr-click" >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Game Date</th>
                  <th>Start Time</th>
                  <th>Venue</th>
                  <th>Squad</th>
                  <th>Opponent</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Last Saved</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td data-order="20150612">12/06/2015</td>
                  <td>19:00</td>
                  <td>Edinburgh</td>
                  <td>U14</td>
                  <td>Jamesons</td>
                  <td><i class="fa fa-circle label-warning"></i> Pending</td>
                  <td data-order="20150601">Alan - 01-06-2015</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td data-order="20150320">20/03/2015</td>
                  <td>19:00</td>
                  <td>Edinburgh</td>
                  <td>U14</td>
                  <td>Jamesons</td>
                  <td><i class="fa fa-circle label-warning"></i> Pending</td>
                  <td data-order="20150601">Alan - 01-06-2015</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

And simple JS:

```
    var table = $('#E_games').dataTable( {
        "order": [ 0, 'desc']
         } );
    table.page.jumpToData( "20/03/2015", 0 );
```

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried this, but maybe [indexOf](http://datatables.net/reference/api/indexOf()) can find today's date for you and you can use the result to calculate what page it is on, then use [page](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page()) to go to that page.

Comment: Thanks, Ok Ill have a go down that road... :)

Comment: Update: So I came across this page.jumpToData() however I'm still having trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix what I needed!

there is an API plugin we can used to do this... I got it to look for todays date with a bit more code however simply we just have to call it but make sure you use DataTable and not dataTable!

```
      var today = new Date();
      var localdate = addLeadingChars(today.getDate()) + '/' + addLeadingChars(today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
      var table = $('#E_games').DataTable( { "order": [ 0, 'desc'] } ).page.jumpToData( localdate, 0 );
```

so swap localdate with 'anything you want to search for' and then the column that is in.

If anyone knows of a better way - let me know!